# How to prove that a list of algebraic numbers with the same symbolic expression is a number field?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

**Definition of number field (K)**:

(1) $0,1 \in K$

(2) $\alpha, \beta \in K \Longrightarrow \alpha \pm \beta   \ and\  \alpha \beta \in K$

(3) $\alpha, \beta \in K$, and $\beta \neq 0 \Longrightarrow \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \in K$

**Now I want to prove the following list of algebraic numbers with the same symbolic expression is a number field by MMA.**

$list=\{a+b \sqrt{2} \mid a, b \in \mathbf{Q}\}$  (**EDIT**: **Q** is **Rational number field**)

```
AlgebraicNumber[Sqrt[2], {a, b}]
```

**The proof process in the textbook is as follows.**

$0=0+0 \sqrt{2} \in list$

$1=1+0 \sqrt{2} \in list$

$Assuming\ \alpha=a+b \sqrt{2}\ and\ \beta=c+d \sqrt{2} \in list$

$Then\ \alpha \pm \beta=(a+b \sqrt{2}) \pm(c+d \sqrt{2})=(a \pm c)+(b \pm d) \sqrt{2} \in list$

$\alpha \beta=(a+b \sqrt{2})(c+d \sqrt{2})=(a c+2 b d)+(a d+b c) \sqrt{2} \in list$

$\begin{aligned} \frac{\alpha}{\beta} &=\frac{a+b \sqrt{2}}{c+d \sqrt{2}}=\frac{(a+b \sqrt{2})(c-d \sqrt{2})}{(c+d \sqrt{2})(c-d \sqrt{2})} \\ &=\frac{(a c-2 b d)+(b c-a d) \sqrt{2}}{c^{2}-2 d^{2}} \\ &=\frac{a c-2 b d}{c^{2}-2 d^{2}}+\frac{b c-a d}{c^{2}-2 d^{2}} \sqrt{2} \in list \end{aligned}$

I would like to know **if there is an automatic MMA command for the above proof process? Or can we repeat the proof process with MMA code?**

**EDIT**

Can we use functions such as `MemberQ` or `FreeQ` to prove that

$0,1 \in list$

$\alpha \pm \beta   \ and\  \alpha \beta \in list$

$\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \in list$

Comment: The problem with using structural operations such as `MemberQ/FreeQ` is that membership in `Q[sqrt(2)]` is an algebraic question. So it is not obvious what to do for example when denominators are present. Also there are underlying assumptions e.g. that parameters `a,b,...` (from the example) are elements of the base field Q. So you really need to apply algebraic methods.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Thank you very much! This problem is not difficult to solve by hand, but it seems not easy to solve by MMA. I thought MMA would have a function or simple code to check whether a list is a number field, but it seems not.

Answer (score 8):

I'll show the hard case, working with quotients. Say we have

```
frac==(a+b*Sqrt[2])/(c+d*Sqrt[2])
```

Let's make the square root into a variable `sqrt2`, satisfying the relation `sqrt2^2==2`. Then convert the fraction expression into a polynomial equality:

```
(a + b*sqrt2) - frac*(c + d*sqrt2)
```

Next extract a Groebner basis with `frac` ordered above `sqrt2` and all else parameters.

```
gb = 
 GroebnerBasis[{(a + b*sqrt2) - frac*(c + d*sqrt2), 
   sqrt2^2 - 2}, {frac, sqrt2}, CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions]

(* Out[607]= {-2 + sqrt2^2, -a c + 
  2 b d + (c^2 - 2 d^2) frac + (-b c + a d) sqrt2} *)
```

We can solve for `frac` as a linear polynomial in `sqrt2` and see this by separating out the constant and `sqrt2` terms.

```
Collect[SolveValues[gb[[2]] == 0, frac], sqrt2]

(*Out[609]= {(a c - 2 b d)/(c^2 - 2 d^2) + ((b c - a d) sqrt2)/(
  c^2 - 2 d^2)} *)
```